# How do I allow only app to view/download files from server?

Tags: passwords, android, access-control

I have an Android app that uploads and downloads pictures from my dedicated server. However, before I go live, I want to know if there is some way I can secure the server to allow only my app to access and view the files on it. The app currently gets the files from the server through a URL. These files are sensitive and I wouldn't want them to be visible to all.

Is there some way I can set a username and password lock on directories on the server and if yes, how do I allow my Android app to open these directories.

Comment: Do users have to be logged into your app to access these resources? Or is access to these resources essentially publicly accessible via your app?

Comment: @thexacre the users have to be logged into the app to access these resources.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use the same authentication method used when logging in to authenticate requests to upload or download? Either by passing the same authentication details or by using a token provided when logging in?

Comment: @thexacre I could do that but I am unsure as to whether sending data via http headers is secure.

Comment: You mention `http`. Does that mean no SSL or do you use `https`?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking two questions (I'm paraphrasing you...)

> Can I allow only my app to access my server?

No, this is impossible. You cannot control the client. Root  phone. Start debugger. Get your key. Create own app with your key.

> How do I secure my server?

Use a security framework for your app server. If, for example, you are using Java Spring, you could use Spring Security which handles authentication and authorization.

Answer (score 0):

> "Can I allow only my app to access my server?"

Yes it is possible to restrict access to the client. I didn't know this back then but it is possible to control who can access files stored on a server using HTTP/HTTPS Header Authentication, which requires a base64 encoded "username:password" combo in the request header to get the file (HTML, IMAGE etc.)

And to prevent header sniffing, Milen's suggestion of using a HTTPS certificate is the way to go because HTTPS encrypts everything using the site's public key (including headers).

### **So how should I have implement this?**

On the Android side, build an app that sends a unique username and password every time the document/image/file needs to be fetched.

On the server side, setup a server script in PHP, or Python, or whatever you are using (more convenient than using .htaccess to restrict access to the files on apache) that base64 decodes the username and password from the request, checks for a correct match, sends the correct content-type header along with the file.

Hopefully this is enough information for whoever needs it. Although I didn't end up testing this, it hopefully should work.

None of the other answers here are majorly correct, but I think I each one contributed in some way to finding a solution to this question.

Answer (score -1):

Pass your username and password to the server from the APP over HTTPS and compare the hash of the password against the hash stored on the server against that username. Follow the 'usual' precautions:

- use a strong hash on the server (SHA256 for example)
- use a salt with the password (any truly random string will do)
- use a strong password (say at least 10 characters with upper and lower case, numbers and punctuation)
- put a small delay in authentication failure (e.g. make your server 'sleep' for 4 or 5 seconds before reporting an authentication failure - to deter serial brute force attacks)
- monitor for multiple failed login attempts and alert/investigate attempted abuses and temporarily lock out source IPs if possible in your architecture.

You can either then return a session token with a limited time duration attached, or just require the username/password pair with every APP to server message.

These are tried and tested ways of managing this process.

Comment: IMHO it is poor practice to send password hashes across. This does not protect against replay attacks, or against an attacker stealing the hash and using it to authenticate itself. This is _somewhat_ mitigated by using HTTPS, but I wouldn't count out MITM, cipher degradation attacks, or other similar attacks. Instead one should use an appropriate keying mechanism, or an appropriate authentication scheme. Again, you're trying to address security of data in transit with security appropriate for data in situ.

Comment: I didn't say pass the hash. It says 'pass your username and password' not 'pass your username and password HASH'

Answer (score -2):

1. Use HTTPS - a decent certificate is like $10, so no excuses there :-)
2. Don't invent your own authentication/authorization mechanisms. Use what smarter people have developed, tested, assessed and tested again. A good starting point is to evaluate [OAuth](http://oauth.net/).

Comment: The 'don't roll your own' ethos has historically been applied to cryptography and not authentication mechanisms where a simple 'username/password' mechanism embedded in the auth request with hashed passwords stored on the server is usually adequate. Sometimes using existing packaged software, like OAUth for exampme brings its own vulnerabilities and management issues - requiring expertise. OAuth was intended for federated authentication mechanisms not for 'solving' the (nonexistent?) roll-your-own issue of self invention.

Comment: Good security requires expertise and profound understanding of the issues at hand. Sometimes packaged software does bring its own issues, but it would be something that hundreds of people would have looked at and possibly addressed the basics, unlike security by obscurity, or asking someone to implement an authentication mechanism but they do not have the expertise to use a well-thought system built by people that know what they're doing. I recommended OAuth as a good starting point, not as a silver bullet to solving all application authentication/authorization problems.